# Implementing Mongoose's 'virtual attributes' in the standard Node.js Mongo driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose supports Virtual Attributes:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

I'm trying to see if there is a relatively easy way to create an "id" virtual attribute for "_id" in the standard mongo driver; I need this for backwards compatibility for an API.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: No, there's not a clean way.   You'd need to create specific object types with the virtual property. Might be easier to just run the object through a function to make the one time modification necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I agree the result is not going to be worth effort to implement this feature.  It's going to be easier to update the client apps that consume this api at this point.